# How to Send Data Over a USB Cable Using C# Without Understanding USB Protocol

Tags: c#, serialization

How do I send low speed serial data over a USB to USB connection using C#? I don't want to have to learn the intricacies of USB communications, and was hoping to use a communications library (like serial COM ports) that comes with 'NET.

Answer (score 3):

For USB device manufacturers, the tried and true way of doing this is using the USB HID class driver - when the device connects to the host, it identifies itself over the USB channel as a device that supports generic USB HID. When the computer sees that device and those identifications, it immediately starts an instance of the generic USB HID driver and attaches it to that endpoint. The driver exposes a simple file-handle interface that allows you to read and write raw bytes to the device.

A user-land program uses the HID API to enumerate all HID devices, filtering the enumerated devices by their vendor ID and product ID field to find the particular device you want. Next, you can obtain a [Windows Object Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29) 'path' to the device driver's user-land interface. Call `CreateFile` on that path to open a file handle to the driver, and then read and write to your heart's content. What you read and write is just a stream of bytes that get sent to the device.

The relevant APIs you'll need to implement this:

- HidD_GetHidGuid
- SetupDiGetClassDevs
- SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
- SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail
- CreateFile
- HidD_GetAttributes
- HidD_GetPreparsedData
- HidD_FreePreparsedData
- HidP_GetCaps
- HidD_GetSerialNumberString
- HidD_... etc

There are several projects available on the internet that show to do this - the DS4Windows project does, since the DualShock4 bluetooth controllers attach as vanilla USB HID devices. Take a look at their source: https://github.com/Jays2Kings/DS4Windows, particularly their `HidDevices.EnumerateDevices` method:

```
    private static IEnumerable<DeviceInfo> EnumerateDevices()
    {
        var devices = new List<DeviceInfo>();
        var hidClass = HidClassGuid;
        var deviceInfoSet = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref hidClass, null, 0, NativeMethods.DIGCF_PRESENT | NativeMethods.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

        if (deviceInfoSet.ToInt64() != NativeMethods.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            var deviceInfoData = CreateDeviceInfoData();
            var deviceIndex = 0;

            while (NativeMethods.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, ref deviceInfoData))
            {
                deviceIndex += 1;

                var deviceInterfaceData = new NativeMethods.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
                deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInterfaceData);
                var deviceInterfaceIndex = 0;

                while (NativeMethods.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData, ref hidClass, deviceInterfaceIndex, ref deviceInterfaceData))
                {
                    deviceInterfaceIndex++;
                    var devicePath = GetDevicePath(deviceInfoSet, deviceInterfaceData);
                    var description = GetBusReportedDeviceDescription(deviceInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData) ?? 
                                      GetDeviceDescription(deviceInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData);
                    devices.Add(new DeviceInfo { Path = devicePath, Description = description });
                }
            }
            NativeMethods.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoSet);
        }
        return devices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the device you want to talk to has a [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) connection you need a converter. The specification is not the same and there are no way to connect a usb cable to a RS232 port.

Comment: To clarify, neither device has a RS-232 port. I was hoping that I could use the serial COM port library in .NET to communicate over a USB to USB connection.

Comment: USB Has a notion of host and device. Using USB to communicate between two computers as it sound, while possible you'll end up in hack land.
Isn't it possible to use ethernet. Think that would be a lot easier.